# Process Builder error: Record rolled back because not all records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header

Tags: error, process-builder

I'm getting the following error in a Process Builder rule, and I'm not sure why. The rule fires when a user lookup field on the Account changes. When that field changes, it changes all of the Account's Contacts ownerId to equal the new field value.

Here's the error:

```
An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate).
UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK) Record rolled back because not all records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header --- for SFDC record with ID : 003A000001VHDehIAH, 

This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.
We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.

Flow Details
Flow Name: Update_Contact_to_Pipeline_Rep
Type: Workflow
Version: 1
Status: Active

Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: Update_Contact_to_Pipeline_Rep-1_Account
Current User: xxUserxx (005A0000005FohB)
Start time: 3/2/2016 2:24 PM
Duration: 28 seconds

How the Interview Started
Chris Thames (005A0000005FohB) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = 001A0000014JsaDIAS
myVariable_current = 001A0000014JsaDIAS
RecursiveCountVariable = 0.00

ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime}
Result
{!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "3/2/2016 2:24 PM"

DECISION: isChangedDecision2_myRule_1_Pipeline_Rep_c
Executed this outcome: isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_Pipeline_Rep_c
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!myVariable_old} (001A0000014JsaDIAS) Is null false
2. {!myVariable_old.Pipeline_Rep__c} (005A0000007DuG5IAK) Does not equal {!myVariable_current.Pipeline_Rep__c} (005A0000005FohBIAS)
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

DECISION: myDecision
Executed this outcome: myRule_1
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_Pipeline_Rep_c} (true) Equals true
2. {!myVariable_current.Pipeline_Rep__c} (005A0000005FohBIAS) Is null false
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

RECORD UPDATE: myRule_1_A1
Find all Contact records where:
AccountId Equals {!myVariable_current.Id} (001A0000014JsaDIAS)
Update the records’ field values.
OwnerId = {!myVariable_current.Pipeline_Rep__c} (005A0000005FohBIAS)
Result
Failed to update records that meet the filter criteria.

Error Occurred: UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK) Record rolled back because not all records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header --- for SFDC record with ID : 003A000001VHDehIAH,
```

Comment: Given the error, one of the contacts that is being updated is throwing an error. And the contact that's causing you the error might be the contact id that was shown in the error. Try updating the owner of that contact and see if any error occurs upon saving it

Comment: @SeanSoriano I updated the contact (003A000001VHDehIAH) mentioned at the very bottom of the error with a new owner and it processed fine.

Comment: how many contact records are associated with the account that you're updating? you can try updating all of the contact owners using developer console execute anonymous and see if any error occurs

Comment: @SeanSoriano there's actually a ton... more than 1,600... which might be the problem in of itself. I'm not totally sure what to do with that....

Comment: Would there be a way to prevent executing the flow if the number of matched records was greater than a number I designate?

Comment: you can invoke classes on your process builder in which you can query then put a limit on the number of records that is being processed.

Comment: @SeanSoriano will I hit the governor limit if I query the number of contacts in the account and it exceeds 1,000?

Comment: @Matt is the issue resolved?

Comment: @Uday not really, I simply work around it at this point. If I hit an error via the PBR for updating the contacts, I deactivate the PBR, change the field on the account, reactivate the PBR, then run a mass update of the contact owners through DataLoader